# Using LIKE to pull out an ID from comma separated string

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, sql-like

I have a table which stores ID's in a comma separated string as follows:

```
field_id_13
------------
1234,5266,3678,4733,7372,5766,2578
```

and I'm using the following Active Record Construct (CI), to pull out the data:

```
$this->db->select("*")
    ->from("channel_data d")
    ->join("channel_titles t","t.entry_id=d.entry_id")
    ->where("d.field_id_13 LIKE '%".$id."%'")
    ->where("t.status","open")
    ->get();
```

The problem is that, sometimes on my search, the ID of '266' will be returned, therefore - because of my % surrounding the clause are returning a result matching against '5266'.

Whats the alternative here to make sure it only returns the correct ID/Rows?

Hopefully this makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use FIND_IN_SET in where condition

```
$this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET('$id',d.field_id_13 ) !=", 0);
```

Comment: it should be greater than 0 like this $this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET('$id',d.field_id_13) > 0", 0);

Comment: @PravinS. Thanks for your suggestion. However FIND_IN_SET returns a value in the range of 1 to N if found. Otherwise 0 will be returned. So we can check `!=` also.

Comment: Yes, but if we use greater than 0, then it will not return any records, if a value is not found in string

Comment: @PravinS. Both are same :-)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way, if not the most elegant, would be to add commas to the start and end of the values in the id field, and then search for the value surrounded by commas as well. In other words:

```
field_id_13
------------
,1234,5266,3678,4733,7372,5766,2578,
```

and:

```
$this->db->select("*")
    ->from("channel_data d")
    ->join("channel_titles t","t.entry_id=d.entry_id")
    ->where("d.field_id_13 LIKE '%,".$id.",%'")
    ->where("t.status","open")
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE field_id_13 REGEXP ('^266,|,266,|266$')`

Replace 266 with your target ID.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6a74/1

Answer (score 0):

The `FIND_IN_SET` solution looks more elegant, but this should work, too:

```
->where("d.field_id_13 REGEXP '[[:<:]]{$id}[[:>:]]'")
```